# Get information about sub-type corresponding to a row with attribute storing a max value

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to retrieve information including address from the distributor that has the highest value in sold:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Distributor_address_ty AS OBJECT (
Street VARCHAR(20),
No VARCHAR(6),
City VARCHAR(15),
Postal_code VARCHAR(6),
Province VARCHAR(2));

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Distributor_ty AS OBJECT (
VAT VARCHAR(15),
Seq_No NUMBER,
Sold NUMBER,
Address Distributor_address_ty)
NOT FINAL;
```

What I've tried is:

```
SELECT VAT, seq_no, sold, 
DEREF(VALUE(d)).address.street AS Street,
DEREF(VALUE(d)).address.No AS Number,
DEREF(VALUE(d)).address.cut AS City,
DEREF(VALUE(d)).address.postal_code AS Postal Code,
DEREF(VALUE(d)).address.province AS Province
FROM (SELECT * FROM distributor d
ORDER BY sold DESC) 
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

but returns the error:
inconsistent datatypes: expected REF got DB:_EXAM.Distributor_ty

suggestion?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with a **complete** example that we can copy/paste and that compiles. At the moment you define some types but there you do not define any tables and there is not `INSERT` statements for sample data so we are left trying to reverse engineer your code from the query. Help us to help you and give a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

1. The table alias `d` is defined in the sub-query and not in the outer query. If you try to use it in the outer query then it will be an invalid identifier;
2. You are not using a `REF` type;
3. `NUMBER` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an unquoted identifier; and
4. The address type does not have a `cut` attribute.

From Oracle 12, use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` and don't try to dereference the address:

```sql
SELECT VAT,
       seq_no,
       sold, 
       d.address.street AS Street,
       d.address.No AS "NUMBER",
       d.address.city AS City,
       d.address.postal_code AS Postal_Code,
       d.address.province AS Province
FROM   distributor d
ORDER BY sold DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

In earlier versions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT VAT,
         seq_no,
         sold, 
         d.address.street AS Street,
         d.address.No AS "NUMBER",
         d.address.city AS City,
         d.address.postal_code AS Postal_Code,
         d.address.province AS Province
  FROM   distributor d
  ORDER BY sold DESC
)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/diIOuwdU)